# How to copy a file by using its inode number?

Tags: cp, inode, special-characters

**This problem is related to Samba and inodes are not necessary.**

---

I have a problem handling a certain file that has some special characters in it. If I search it by its `inode` it will list the file:

```
 $ find . -inum 90505400 -exec ls {} \;
./12 String Quartet No. 16 in F Major Op. 135: Der schwer gefa?te Entschlu?: Grave, ma non troppo tratto (Mu? es sein ?) - Allegro (Es mu? sein !).flac
```

However, if I then proceed to use `cp` or `rm` on the file it will throw a `file not found` error (in German 'Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden'):

```
 $ find . -inum 90505400 -exec cp {} ne.flac \;
cp: './12 String Quartet No. 16 in F Major Op. 135: Der schwer gefa?te Entschlu?: Grave, ma non troppo tratto (Mu? es sein ?) - Allegro (Es mu? sein !).flac' kann nicht zum Lesen geöffnet werden: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

I wonder, if I can copy the file with another command that uses the inode directly. I also had this problem for some time now. I can remove all files with `rm *`, but I would like to fix the broken filename.

---

It is an `ext4` filesystem which I mount on a Raspi from an external USB HDD with this line (changed obfuscated paths and IPs):

```
UUID=e3f9d42a-9703-4e47-9185-33be24b81c46   /mnt/test   ext4    rw,auto,defaults,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=15 0 2
```

I then share it with samba:

```
[mybook]
path=/mnt/test
public = yes
browseable = yes
writeable = yes
comment = test
printable = no
guest ok = no
```

And I mount this on a Lubuntu 16 with this:

```
//192.168.1.190/test         /home/ben/test               cifs auto,nofail,username=XXX,password=XXX,uid=1000,gid=1000
```

I connect to the Lubuntu 16 through `VNC` from a Macbook. Or I `SSH` directly into it. I am just telling this for full information.

I also mount the share on that Macbook (and others) in Finder. Finder does not display the filename correctly.

[image]

---

### After a useful comment from a user, I realized I should try to manipulate the file on the host with the original filesystem instead of trying to do it over samba.

`SSH`ing into the host reveals this filename (look at the sign with `0xF022` after '135'):

```
'12 String Quartet No. 16 in F Major Op. 135 Der schwer gefa?te Entschlu? Grave, ma non troppo tratto (Mu? es sein ) - Allegro (Es mu? sein !).flac'
```

**I then was able to copy the file with `cp` on the host itself.**

(In case anybody wonders how I came to the filename: I split a summed up `flac` file with it's `cue` sheet into the separate files and they got named automatically.)

Comment: Is the file on an NTFS filesystem?

Comment: @bomben, heh, ok, done. Glad that it helped.

Comment: if you use : 'find . -inum 90505400 -exec cp "{}" ne.flac ' ?

Comment: ie prevent the shell from splitting. One version using find and xargs: find . -inum 90505400 |xargs -I '{}' cp '{}' ne.flac

Comment: I reverted your most recent edit. If one of the solutions below solve your issue, then consider accepting it. You may also suggest edits to existing answers. If none of the answers are helpful, but you have your own answer that is better, please provide it as a proper answer (not as an edit to the question). You may later accept your own answer.  Accepting an answer marks the question as resolved.  Please also see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers and https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @StefanSkoglund You mean with the quotes arount the braces? Does not work either.

Comment: The quotes around the `{}` does not do a thing. That's cargo cult coding.

Comment: @they I edited my question because I think it was stupid to not check it on the host system but instead doing something via inodes over samba. I wanted to prevent people reading a lot of text just to recognise it does not at all relate to their problem.

Comment: The unicode character following `Op. 135` shows as 0xF022 which falls into https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas - i.e. not globally unique unicode character.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

All of `open()` (for copying), `rename()` and `unlink()` (removal) work by filenames. There's really nothing that would work on an inode directly, apart from low-level tools like `debugfs`.

If you can remove the file with `rm *`, you should be able to rename it with `mv ./12* someothername.flac`, or copy it with `cp ./12* newfile.flac` (assuming `./12*` matches just that file). `find` in itself shouldn't be that different.

But you mentioned Mac, and I think Mac requires filenames to be valid UTF-8 and that might cause issues if the filenames are broken. Linux doesn't names that are invalid UTF-8, but of course there, too, some tools might react oddly. (I haven't tested.) Having Samba in there might not help either.

Assuming that has something to do with the issue, you could try to SSH in to the host with the filesystem, skipping the intermediary parts, and rename the files there.

Comment: Thanks again! Obviously, doing it on the host filesystem instead of over samba should have been my first approach.

Answer (score 7):

It is not possible to open a file via its inode. This is a deliberate aspect of the design of the operating system, because opening a file via its inode would bypass permissions.

Calling `find . -inum $inode_number -exec … {} \;` is as close as it gets to act on a file based on its inode. But this does use the file name, and it is guaranteed to work on a non-buggy system.

The `?` in the output represent bytes that do not make up a valid character. Presumably one piece of software is presenting a legacy 8-bit encoding to a tool that expects UTF-8.

I'm not sure if this could be a symptom of macOS tools working with a file name with an invalid encoding. Just in case, try running the commands in a C locale. This means that all file names will be treated as sequences of bytes, so there are no invalid characters (as far as the user land tools are concerned — the kernel might still have trouble if the remote server is giving it bad data).

```
LC_ALL=C find . -inum 90505400 -exec cp {} ne.flac \;
```

Another approach you can try is to run `export LC_ALL=C` then type `mv 12` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> for completion.

If that doesn't work, then the problem is a buggy filesystem which reacts differently when told to retrieve the metadata of a file and when told to open a file. This could be a bug or a misconfiguration on the Samba client or on the Samba server. Or perhaps Samba is fully configured for UTF-8 and is unable to cope with a file name on the server that is not encoded in UTF-8. I recommend checking on the server whether the file name is encoded in UTF-8. If it isn't, rename it on the server. If it is, you have a problem with your Samba configuration.

Comment: @bomben Since you saw `?` in the file name on the server as well, it's likely that both machines are configured for UTF-8 and the file name is in an 8-bit encoding (presumably latin1). And so on the server, `mv 12<TAB> '12 String Quartet No. 16 in F Major Op. 135 Der schwer gefaßte Entschluß Grave, ma non troppo tratto (Muß es sein) - Allegro (Es muß sein!).flac' should work.